# Most efficient way to know the size of a remote CMIS folder

Tags: cmis

A CMIS folder can contain many sub-folders and documents, so they can be arbitrarily big.

I would like to warn the user before downloading a folder.
For instance: `You are about to download 35TB. Are you sure?`
It would also be useful for a progress bar.

What is the most efficient way to know the recursive size of a remote CMIS folder.

My naive approach (simplified code) with [getDecendants](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.7.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/Folder.html#getDescendants%28int%29):

```
// Get all descendants
depth = 99999999; // By the way, this is not great
descendants = cmisFolder.getDescendants(depth);

// Add up all sizes
size = 0;
foreach(descendants) {
  size += descendant.getSize();
}
```

Is there a more efficient approach, with less traffic between me and the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a query is bit more efficient because it allows you to filter non-document objects (e.g. folders) and documents without content. It also returns a flat list, which is easier to traverse, and supports paging, which may help client and server if many documents are returned.

Comment: how to use query?